# Windows scripting FOR command to rename all files in a directory

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to rename all the files present in a Windows directory using **FOR** command as follows at the command prompt:

```
for %1 in (*.*) do ren %1 test%1
```

E.g. This renames a file **enc1.ctl** to **testenc1.ctl** **enc2.ctl**  to **testenc2.ctl**

Thats not what i want. What i want is 
**enc1.ctl** renamed to **test1.ctl**   **enc2.ctl** renamed to **test2.ctl**

How do i do that?

---

@Akelunuk: 
Thanks, that w kind of works but i have files names as

**h263_enc_random_pixels_1.ctl , h263_enc_random_pixels_2.ctl** which i want to rename to

**test1.ctl and test2.ctl** respectively

Then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of files, (say 10), you can use

```
for /L %1 in (1,1,10) do ren enc%1.ctl test%1.ctl
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got it!

```
for %1 in (.) do ren %1 t%1
```

and then:

```
ren tenc*.* test*.*
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible in batch, but then again I never mastered this primitive language... :-P

If CMD isn't mandatory, but you can't use a good file renamer, you can do that with WSH:

```
var path= "E:/tmp";

var fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folder = fso.GetFolder(path);
var files = new Enumerator(folder.files);
for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext())
{
  var file = files.item();
  var fileName = file.Name;
  var p = /^enc(\d+)\.ctl$/.exec(fileName);
  if (p != null)
  {
    var newFileName = "test" + p[1] + ".ctl";
    // Optional feedback
    WScript.echo(fileName + " -----> " + newFileName);
    file.Move(newFileName);
  }
}
```

Of course, put that in a file.js
I actually tested with `file.Copy(file.ParentFolder + "/SO/" + newFileName);` to avoid loosing files...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This renames all files in directory for filter file types with PREFIX and today's date and time

```
@echo ON
cls
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (set myfiledate=%%~ta echo !myfiledate!)

echo Date format = %myfiledate%
echo dd = %myfiledate:~0,2%
echo mm = %myfiledate:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %myfiledate:~6,4%
echo.
echo Time format = %myfiledate%
echo hh = %myfiledate:~11,2%
echo mm = %myfiledate:~14,2%
echo AM = %myfiledate:~17,2%
echo.
echo Timestamp = %myfiledate:~0,2%_%myfiledate:~3,2%_%myfiledate:~6,4%-%myfiledate:~11,2%_%myfiledate:~14,2%_%myfiledate:~17,2%
ECHO "TEST..." > "test-%myfiledate:~0,2%_%myfiledate:~3,2%_%myfiledate:~6,4%-TIME-%myfiledate:~11,2%_%myfiledate:~14,2%_%myfiledate:~17,2%.txt"
PAUSE
```

This echos successfuly the date modified and time as a postfix but doesnt parse the info into the rename. I cant figure out why, but it is very close. Maybe someone cant tweak to suit your purpose.

```
@echo ON
setlocal
cls
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (set myfiledate=%%~ta echo !myfiledate!)

:DATETIME
echo Date format = %myfiledate%
echo dd = %myfiledate:~0,2%
echo mm = %myfiledate:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %myfiledate:~6,4%

echo Time format = %myfiledate%
echo hh = %myfiledate:~11,2%
echo mm = %myfiledate:~14,2%
echo AM = %myfiledate:~17,2%
 = %myfiledate:~17,2%
echo.

echo Timestamp = %myfiledate:~0,2%_%myfiledate:~3,2%_%myfiledate:~6,4%-%myfiledate:~11,2%_%myfiledate:~14,2%_%myfiledate:~17,2%
ECHO "TEST..." > "test-%myfiledate:~0,2%_%myfiledate:~3,2%_%myfiledate:~6,4%-TIME-%myfiledate:~11,2%_%myfiledate:~14,2%_%myfiledate:~17,2%.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.pdf /t:a /a:-d /b /s') do call :RENAME "%%a"

:RENAME
REM for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=/ " %%a in ('dir %%a /t:w^|find "/"') do (
ren %%a "3DC-test-OFF-ELE-%myfiledate:~0,2%_%myfiledate:~3,2%_%myfiledate:~6,4%-TIME-%myfiledate:~11,2%_%myfiledate:~14,2%_%myfiledate:~17,2%~x1")
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```