# Batch: rename all the files and subfolders

Tags: loops, batch-file, rename

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /ad /s /b "C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\renameFolders"') do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
  set N=%%f
  set N=!N: =_!
  ren "%%f" "!N!"
)
```

How can I rename all the files and subfolders?
I failed to loop through and rename all the subfolders.

File Structure:
test:

```
file 2.txt
file 1.txt
folder 1
test.bat
```

folder 1:

```
folder 2
file 3.txt
```

folder 2:
file 4.txt

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191351/windows-dos-scripting-for-command-to-rename-all-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Is the problem that it renames the directories but not the files, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it you have three problems:

1. Using the /ad switch means you will only process the directories and not the files
2. `set N=%%f` will cause N to get the full name including the path, since that's what `dir /b` returns
3. The recursion needs to be reversed.  If you rename "folder 1" to "folder_1" then when you examine "folder 1/folder 2" the path isn't valid anymore.

Fixing (1) is just removing `/ad`
Fixing (2) is use `set N=%%~nxf`
I'm not sure yet how to fix #3.  I found by accident that repeatedly running the script with (1) & (2) fixed will eventually get all the files renamed.  But I'm sure there's a better answer out there.

Comment: The names must include the full path; otherwise, how the files/folders below the first level will be located? Or at any level if the Batch file was started in a different directory?

Comment: setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('DIR /b /s /ad') DO (
 SET "old=%%D"
 SET new=!old: =_!
 if not !new! == !old! ren "!old!" "!new!"
 
)

PAUSE <br /> What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: Can I ask more about the first part? What is the use of pushd and popd? Does it store the current directory? And call the renameFile function? And popd? And exit the script? No idea of the first part... please explain a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @Aacini - the rename command takes two arguments, original filename (with path) and new filename.  The new filename part shouldn't have a path on it.

Comment: But where's the path ya think shouldn't be there in the new filename?

Comment: %%f contains the full path and filename.  %%~nxf contains just the filename portion.

Comment: @Tim Amaranth: See the answers in the question you are refering to (you should place your comments there :-)

Comment: @David Winant: The second argument of `ren` command may or may not include a full path (this is not a problem). The only requirement is that both paths be the same.

Comment: @Aacini: I don't know (or do not remember) when the `ren` command's second argument was allowed to include the path but the following produces a syntax error message in Windows XP & Windows 7: `ren D:\abc D:\abc1` (assuming `D:\abc` exists). And this command works: `ren D:\abc abc1`.

Comment: @AndriyM: Yes, you are right! I started using MS-DOS at version 2.1 (don't ask for my age! :-) and still in version 4.0 the REN command description indicate "Any drive designation and paths are ignored for the new filename". I don´t know when this detail became a syntax error. Originally REN renames files only and MOVE can rename subdirs, but it may move the dir to a new place so I used to always give paths to the new dir name. As far as I know, the ability of REN to rename subdirs is undocumented (by Microsoft, I mean...). David Winant: I apologize for my comment, was my mistake...

Comment: Excuse me. I was pretty sure that this solution will not work because the order problem. It worked correctly? I'm just curious...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the ORDER in wich the rename of the folders must be done. The deepest folder must be renamed first and the rename process must go on upwards until reach the top level folder. The only way to do that is via a recursive subroutine that process each existing folder this way:

```
Rename the files in this folder.
For each folder in this folder:
    Process it recursively.
    Rename it.
```

Also, note that not all files/folders must be renamed, just those that have spaces in the name; otherwise the REN command issue an error. The Batch file below take in the first argument the top-level folder to process:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
pushd %1
call :ProcessThisFolder
popd
exit /b

:ProcessThisFolder
REM Rename the files in this folder.
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set "old=%%f"
    set new=!old: =_!
    if not !new! == !old! ren "!old!" "!new!"
)
REM For each folder in this folder:
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    REM Process it recursively.
    cd %%d
    call :ProcessThisFolder
    cd ..
    REM Rename it.
    set "old=%%d"
    set new=!old: =_!
    if not !new! == !old! ren "!old!" "!new!"
)
```

**EDIT**

The problem with the original method is the order in wich the renames will be executed. Suppose that the result of `dir /s /b ...` is:

```
C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\renameFolders\file 1.txt
C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\renameFolders\file 2.txt
C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\renameFolders\folder 1
C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\renameFolders\folder 1\file 3.txt
C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\renameFolders\folder 1\folder 2
```

When the line 3 is processed `folder 1` is renamed to `folder_1`, so at this point the names in lines 4 and 5 are no longer valid. The first rename must be done over `file 3.txt` and `folder 2` and then proceed upwards to above folders, but the lines displayed by `dir` command are sorted in alphabetical order and the other available orders don't help in this case.

The first part of the program above works this way:

```
pushd %1                 Save current directory and do a CD %1
call :ProcessThisFolder  Call the subroutine defined in this same file below
popd                     Do a CD to the directory saved by previous PUSHD
exit /b                  Terminate here this Batch file; otherwise the lines
. . .                    below would be executed again
```

You may review the operation of any command by executing it with /? parameter, for example: `pushd /?`.

Comment: Does the CD%1 the same to cd %%d in terms of path (or as you said, it helps going to the deepest directory to do the job dir cannot do?)? And, how about if we pushd %1 (the path should be where I place the bat file), then after calling :ProcessThisFolder (it loops through the whole directory by the use of "cd %%d" and "cd ..", and it returns to %1 directory. Is that right? Cos I am always confused by the paths problems in BATCH.

Comment: Yes, your description is correct. In the subroutine we may also use `pushd %%d` and `popd` instead of `cd %%d` and `cd ..`, but in this case we are sure that each folder is one level down from the previous one so `pushd` is not necessary. `pushd` is used when we have not idea of where is the current directory and want to return to it later.