# Converting a script & using it

Tags: jpeg, file-extension

I've been googling to find out how I can insert file extensions to multiple files that have no extension (filename to filename.txt), as well as correcting erroneous extensions (from an incorrectly saved .txt to .jpg, for example), as well as excluding other files/folders from this renaming process.

One page i stumbled upon in particular, is very similar to mine: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1185203

On the second page of this thread, there is a script posted by tinge, that seems to be the solution I'm looking for (can someone verify this?):

---

```
#!/bin/bash
program () {
    FILETYPE="$1"
# Select all files in current directory, and process one at a time
for FILE in *; do
    # Strip of any extension, and save to FILE1
    FILE1=${FILE%\.*}

    # If it's the same afterward, then there was no extension - rename it
    if [ "$FILE1" = "$FILE" ]; then
    while [ -f "${FILE1}.${FILETYPE}" ] ; do
        FILE1="${FILE1}_1"
    done
        mv "$FILE" "$FILE1.$FILETYPE"
    fi
done
exit 0
}

case $1 in
    --help)   echo;echo;echo "Usage: noext.sh filetype i.e. noext.sh JPG changes all     files with no extension to a .JPG";echo;echo;echo
    ;;
    -h)   echo;echo;echo "Usage: noext.sh filetype i.e. noext.sh JPG changes all files     with no extension to a .JPG";echo;echo;echo
    ;;
    *) program $1
    ;;
esac
```

---

I'm not sure it copied over correctly (I tried to follow the 4-space indenting rule.. I think I butchered it, lol), but it's on the second page of the thread's link I posted. Being unfamiliar with scripts, I do not know how to handle it.

I am using Windows 7.

Can someone please help?

Thank you,
-B

Comment: You can't use `bash` scripts on Windows. Not without installing a *NIX environment, anyway (like Cygwin). Apart from that, this script will will only add an extension you specify to files without extension; there is no detecting of correct types going on at all. Also, extensions serve to identify the type of a file; without it, you can know what a file "should" be only some of the time, by looking at the contents (which is what *NIX command `file` does, and again you can't do easily on vanilla Windows).

Comment: This is a Linux bash script, and won't run on Windows without having Cygwin or something similar installed. Linux <> Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191351/windows-dos-scripting-for-command-to-rename-all-files-in-a-directory ?

Answer (score 0):

As you might have been able to see, this script starts with the line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Which means, in [unix environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009192/how-does-the-work/3009280#3009280) that you want that script executed by the bash binary. However, in Windows 7 there is no bash preinstalled. Windows scripts and Unix scripts are mostly the same thing, but they are written in a different language and they usually don't understand each other.

You would probably like a version of this script for the Windows's `cmd.exe`, which is the builtin shell in Windows.

Otherwise, if you actually want to execute *this* particular file, you can install some compiled version of bash (like the one which comes with tools such as MinGW, Cygwin or Git).

If you just want to rename files, you may do better with some other tools, like the one provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8822951/488191) or [answers to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191351/windows-dos-scripting-for-command-to-rename-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Okay, so after reading yours and others' comments, is there another way I can:

"insert file extensions to multiple files that have no extension (filename to filename.txt), as well as correcting erroneous extensions (from an incorrectly saved .txt to .jpg, for example), as well as excluding other files/folders from this renaming process" ?

Judging from Amadan's comment, the script I (tried to) copy and pasted won't work for my endeavors. EDIT* I'm not trying to rename files, but manage the extensions rather.